# Design pattern to map derived types to list of new type

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, types, factory-pattern

I have a list of derived types I want to map to a list of another type. Each derived type maps differently to the new type.

Is there any pattern to do this without casting each types and that keeps the logic of the mapping outside of the type (in a factory).

Here's an example, I'd like to find an alternative to GetFlatSwitch, something like GetFlat :

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      List<Base> list = new List<Base>() { new DerivedA() { A = "A" }, new DerivedB() { B = "B" }};

      List<Flat> flatList = list.Select(x => Factory.GetFlat(x)).ToList(); // not working
      List<Flat> switchFlatList = list.Select(x => Factory.GetFlatSwitch(x)).ToList(); // works, but casting each element
    }

    static class Factory
    {
      public static Flat GetFlat(Base baseObj)
      {
        return new Flat();
      }

      public static Flat GetFlat(DerivedA a)
      {
        return new Flat() { A = a.A };
      }

      public static Flat GetFlat(DerivedB b)
      {
        return new Flat() { B = b.B };
      }

      public static Flat GetFlatSwitch(Base baseObj)
      {
        switch (baseObj.MyType)
        {
          case MyTypeEnum.A:
            DerivedA a = baseObj as DerivedA;
            return new Flat() { A = a.A };
          case MyTypeEnum.B:
            DerivedB b = baseObj as DerivedB;
            return new Flat() { B = b.B };
          default:
            return new Flat();
        }
      }
    }

    enum MyTypeEnum
    {
      A, B
    }

    abstract class Base
    {
      public abstract MyTypeEnum MyType { get; }
    }

    class DerivedA : Base
    {
      public override MyTypeEnum MyType
      {
        get
        {
          return MyTypeEnum.A;
        }
      }
      public string A { get; set; }
    }

    class DerivedB : Base
    {
      public override MyTypeEnum MyType
      {
        get
        {
          return MyTypeEnum.B;
        }
      }
      public string B { get; set; }
    }

    class Flat
    {
      public string A { get; set; }

      public string B { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a *design pattern*, it seems like you need something like [*AutoMapper*](http://automapper.org/):

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively
>   complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to
>   another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so
>   why not invent a tool to do it for us?

Using that library you configure type-to-type mappings so you can call a method to map a type to other type (for example `mapper.Map<A, B>(a, b)`).